# (->) arrow operator and (.) dot operator , class pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

In C++ we know that for a pointer of class we use (`->`) arrow operator to access the members of that class like here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class myclass{
    private:
        int a,b;
    public:
        void setdata(int i,int j){
            a=i;
            b=j;
        }
};

int main() {
    myclass *p;
    p = new myclass;
    p->setdata(5,6);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I create an array of `myclass`.

```
p=new myclass[10];
```

when I go to access `myclass` members through (`->`) arrow operator, I get the following error:

```
base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'myclass'
```

but while I access class members through (`.`) operator, it works. These things make me confused. Why do I have to use the (`.`) operator for an array of class?

Comment: Show, how did you get access to elements in arrays. Perhaps, you did something like this: `p[0]->setdata(5,6);`, which, of course, incorrect, since `p[0]` is no more a pointer.

Comment: Please check this link It may answer your question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462895/how-to-dynamically-declare-an-array-of-objects-with-a-constructor-in-c

Comment: Try understanding what array really is and then move on to classes.

Comment: what members are you trying to access?  and how?  they are all private.  Please post the actual code that reproduces the problem

Comment: I added the following to your program and still got no errors (and don't expect any)    p=new myclass[10];
  p->setdata(1,2);

Comment: are we to assume you are saying p[2]->setdata?

Comment: @xaxxon, yes I am saying p[2]-> setdata

Comment: Also: use `std::array`, or `std::vector`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you should read about difference between [pointers and reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c) that might help you understand your problem.

In short, the difference is:
when you declare `myclass *p` it's a pointer and you can access it's members with `->`, because `p` points to memory location.

But as soon as you call `p=new myclass[10];` `p` starts to point to array and when you call `p[n]` you get a reference, which members must be accessed using `.`.
But if you use `p->member = smth` that would be the same as if you called `p[0].member = smth`, because number in `[]` is an offset from `p` to where search for the next array member, for example `(p + 5)->member = smth` would be same as `p[5].member = smth`

Comment: Some improvements: you can write `p[0]` in first case(`myclass *p`) and `p->setdata(42, 42)` in second(`p=new myclass[10];`) as well. Doesn't matter, what did you use, `new` or `new[]`.

Comment: "(p + (sizeof(myclass) * 5).member = smth would be same as p[5].member = smth" - actually not, because the compiler automatically operates in units of the pointer-to object's size when adding an integer to a pointer, so simply "*(p + 5)" is already the same as "p[5]".

Comment: @Opsenas `(p+5).member`, is it correct? `*(p+5).member` or `(P+5)->member`, is it the correct way to access p[5] ??

Comment: @aaroh (*(p+5)).member and (p+5)->member are both legit if you defined p as pointer

Comment: @Opsenas But in your answer, you are using `(p+5).member`. Is it correct??

Comment: @aaroh tbh i've got lost, yes you're correct, fixed

Answer (score 10):

Note that for a pointer variable x

```
myclass *x;
```

- `*x` means "get the object that x points to"
- `x->setdata(1, 2)` is the same as `(*x).setdata(1, 2)` and finally
- `x[n]` means "get the n-th object in an array".

So for example `x->setdata(1, 2)` is the same as `x[0].setdata(1, 2)`.

Answer (score 6):

Because by using [] like p[3] you are already dereferencing the pointer to array + index shift. After that you have to use ".", since p[3] is an object, not a pointer.

Comment: No , he means the following: "p=new myclass[10]; but then , when i go to access myclass members through (->) arrow operator". He tries to do the trick p[N]->setdata(5,6), 0 <= N < 10. But it's not correct.

Answer (score 4):

After...

```
MyClass* p = new myclass[10];
```

...p is a pointer to an array of MyClass objects.  The "pointer to an array" thing has to be delt with first.  Whenever you have a pointer to an array, `p[n]` effectively gives you a *reference* to the nth element in the array, so you effectively have a `MyClass&`.  *That's* why `.` is then needed to access `MyClass` members ala `p[n].member`, and why the pointer-specific `->` notation is erroneous in this case....

Note that `p->member` (for any member) is still valid and equivalent to `p[0].member`, so you can only use it for accessing the first element in the array.  I strongly recommend you don't use it at all whenever you're in a programmatic context where 'p' is known to be pointer to the array, as it hides the fact that `p` is an array.  Sometimes though you may create another pointer - say `q` - with the purpose of refering to a single array element - may or may not be `[0]` - and in those situation's it's fair to use `q->member`.  Variables like `q` may be used for iteration over the array too.  But, sometime you're going to need to `delete[] p;` - so you won't tend to change `p` beforehands... you don't want to lose track of the `p[0]` address or `delete[] p;` will be Undefined Behaviour (which is allowed to be implementation defined and happens to be on Windows if `p` still points within the array, but won't be portable).

Answer (score 3):

```
myclass *ptr;

ptr = new myclass();     // ptr points to a single object
ptr->doSomething();      // calls doSomething on the object _pointed to_

ptr = new myclass[10];   // ptr points to multiple objects
ptr->doSomething();      // calls doSomething on the first object _pointed to_
(ptr+1)->doSomething();  // calls doSomething on the second object _pointed to_

auto val = ptr[2];       // fetches a reference to the second _object_ to val.
val.doSomething();       // calls doSomething on the _object reference_ val.
```

In other words, when indexing the array to fetch the n'th element, you're not fetching a *pointer* to the n'th element, you're fetching a reference to the actual object, and the members of that need to be accessed using `.` syntax.

Comment: @xaxxon The problem would (as far as I can see) stem from him trying `p[x]->doSomething()`, when the operator [] actually _returns a reference_ that needs to be called with `.`

Comment: yeah, that's why I'm a bit miffed he didn't actually post code to reproduce it.

Comment: @xaxxon: He showed the working code, then said "Then I create a array of "myclass"" and shows how (`p=new myclass[10];`) but doesn't list the code that he must have had to produce the error - something like `p[2]->doSomething();`.

Comment: Yeah, but he didn't say that, and p->doSomething still works fine.

Comment: @xaxxon: it does for a certain definition of "works", but if he had to ask the question then he probably didn't know what it was doing anyway (i.e. affecting element `[0]`).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its insightful to consider that, given

```
myclass obj;
auto p = &obj;  // avoid `new` with plain pointers. That combination is
               //  safer replaced by unique_ptr or std::vector.
```

the following will all work and are equivalent:

```
p->setdata(5, 6);
(*p).setdata(5, 6);
p[0].setdata(5, 6);
0[p].setdata(5, 6);
```

Showing that `[]` is really a pointer-dereferencing operator, just with the extra functionality that you can add offsets into a plain C-array.

It's generally questionable to use C-arrays in C++ code; the obvious alternative to your example is `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<myclass> array(10);
```

Here, `array[n]` can be used much like previously `p[n]`, but

- You don't get any stupid pointer-ideas, because there are no pointers in the interface
- You get proper automatic memory management, i.e. when the array goes out of scope it automatically deletes the objects and its memory
- You can get bounds-checks if you want (`array.at(n)`)
- You can easily loop over the whole array, with (C++11) `for(auto& obj: array){...}`.

Comment: Since you've mentioned C++11, you may also want to be aware of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: Good point, though I don't think it really belongs in this question. (We're talking objects/arrays on the heap here. Automatic C-style arrays and `std::array` are on the stack – which is oftentimes advantageous!)