# initializing arrays of vectors on the heap, c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, initialization

My goal is to create an array of vectors (with a capacity of 10 integers for each vector) on the heap. I can create my array easily enough:

```
vector<int>* test = new vector<int>[NUM_VERTS];
```

However, this creates an array of empty vectors. I know each vector will store at least 10 ints and so I want to create the vectors with size 10 to start with to avoid having them re-size themselves multiple times (I'm reading in a big file and so efficiency is important). How can I modify the statement above so that it does what I want?

As a side note, I'm using VS 2013 and struggling with its debugger. When I run the debugger and look at the contents of `test` above, it shows me the memory address of the area it points to but not the contents stored at the address. Does anyone know how I can view the contents instead of the address?

Thanks

PS I'm creating the array of vectors on the heap instead of the stack because the array is extremely large (just under a million entries). When I tried to create it on the stack I got a stack overflow error.

Comment: Dynamically allocating a `vector` is very uncommon, and doing that for an array of them is practically unheard of. Use `vector<vector<int>> test;` or maybe `array<vector<int>, NUM_VERTS> test;` if `NUM_VERTS` is known at compile time.

Comment: @Praetorian The reason I'm using an array of vectors is because I thought it would be faster than using a vector of vectors. As I mentioned, the file I'm reading in is really big and so I want to be as efficient as possible.

Comment: When you use `new []` operator to allocate memory, the only constructor that can be used to initialize the objects is the default constructor.

Comment: There shouldn't be any discernible performance difference between having an array of vectors or a vector of vectors because the outer container in both cases has contiguous storage.

Comment: @Praetorian Is there any reason aside from it being unconventional to avoid making an array of vectors?

Comment: Oh no, you misunderstood what I was saying. There's nothing wrong with making a statically sized array of vectors if that's what you need. The odd bit was opting for `new[]` (using that is almost always the wrong choice) instead of a vector of vectors.

Comment: @Praetorian But if a vector of vectors and an array of vectors created using new [] are equivalent as the answer says, and if vectors elements are already on the heap, aren't vectors of vectors and arrays of vectors basically the same thing? Obviously I can't use the array of vectors option here because I can only use the default constructor when invoking the new [] operator. But what are the other reasons that using new[] is the wrong choice?

Comment: All the usual gotchas of manual memory management apply to `new[]`, along with the additional requirement that you now need to call `delete[]` and not `delete` to deallocate. And `new[]` will construct each element, which is typically not what you want because you don't want to/can't use default construction. Note that you can [call a constructor taking arguments using an initializer list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8463006/241631) (cc @RSahu), but that doesn't help if you only know the number of elements at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `vector` of `vector`s that is not the same as an array but for your use case it should be equivalent:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > test(NUM_VERTS, std::vector<int>(10));
```

there's no need to allocate it with new because `vector` elements are already on the heap.

If you need the pointer to the first contained vector you can just use

```
std::vector<int> *p = &test[0];
```

and use `p` as if it was an heap-allocated array of vectors (all the elements of a `vector` are guaranteed to be consecutive in memory).