# Dynamically allocating array of objects like int

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic, constructor

In order to create an array of `int`s dynamically, I need to do `int *a = new int[20];`.

Is there a similar way to create an array of objects or structs?

For example, I need a dynamically allocated array of objects of `class A`, how should I declare it(Syntax)?

What constructor would be called on each object(if at all any constructor is called)?

Comment: You could `A* a = new A[20];`, and the default ctor will be called.

Comment: Could I recommend `std::vector` instead of `new` expression?

Comment: @NickyC I want to understand how that would work. I know I can use `std::vector`. But How does it actually work?

Comment: This is already answered here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462895/how-to-dynamically-declare-an-array- ​of-objects-with-a-constructor-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462895/how-to-dynamically-declare-an-array-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bof-objects-with-a-constructor-in-c) Google is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using this line:

```
A* a = new A[N];
```

**How it works?**

the `new` keyword will allocate `N` sequential block in the heap. Each block has a size of `sizeof(A)` so the total size in bytes is `N*sizeof(A)`. Allocating those objects in memory is ensured done by calling the default constructor `N` times.

**Alternative:**

Use `std::vector` instead. It will do all the work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Using arrays with pointer:

```
A* a = new A [20];
```

Without pointers

```
A a [20];
```

I suggest to use vectors:

```
//init
std::vector<A> aList;

//reserve memory size - not necessary 
aList.reserve (20);

 //put elements in
 aList.push_back (A ());

 //access elements
 aList [0];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax(c++):**

**ClassName *classObject = new ClassName;**

For example,
Let's assume a class called car.

```
car *obj = new car;    

car *obj = new car[n];  // n objects will be created by calling the def. constructor
```