# How to use constructor with arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

> Hello, I want to pass parameters into class using constructor. Is it even possible? 
>   NOW I GOT THIS DECLARED:

```
flight *flight = new flight[random];
```

okay? Now how do I call that *flight class's constructor? I declared this so I cannot call the constructor it says "two times declared" bla bla. 
Can't I do like:

```
flight fl;//assuming I have null constructor too
fl(5);//assuming it takes one argument only.
```

Is there no way that could work?

Can't

```
flight *flight = new flight[random];
```

and start the constructor at the same time?

Comment: There's to little information in your question. All we can say for certain is that `_no[i]` is probably out of bounds (if `i` is the number of elements in the array). We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to help you more. Also, I suggest you take a look at [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of using pointer or arrays.

Comment: Most array problems in C++ can be solved by using a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to dynamically declare an array of objects with a constructor in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462895/how-to-dynamically-declare-an-array-of-objects-with-a-constructor-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You can only initialize all elements with the default constructor (the constructor with no parameters):
`* flight=new flight[number]();`

If you want each object seperately initialized with a different value, you need to either encapsulate them in a new class (like `FlightArray`) that has the code in the constructor, or call an `Init()` method after the constructor.

Comment: You are right; I adjusted it. Sorry. Guess I shouldn‘t answer questions before I had my second coffee.