# c++ How do I call a constructor with arguments of a class that is inside an array of structures when I create the array of structures?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, structure, new-operator

How can I pass constructor args to a class that is in an array of structs?
I'm trying to use a linked list implementation.
I have an array of Regions that each have a linkedList, Sll.  (Actually I'll have a 2D array of these.)  I can't find/figure out the syntax to actually call the constructor using non-default parameter / arguments.

I want to keep the Sll as a class.

```
class Sll
{
  public:
  unsigned long count;
  unsigned long uMaxEntries;
  void *pDataArray;
  int iSizeOfEachEntry;
  Sll( unsigned long uInSizeOfEachEntry,  unsigned long uInitNumEntries = INIT_NUM_ENTRIES );
}

Sll::Sll(unsigned long uInSizeOfEachEntry, unsigned long uInitNumEntries)
{
  uMaxEntries = uInitNumEntries;
  iSizeOfEachEntry = uInSizeOfEachEntry;
  pDataArray = malloc(iSizeOfEachEntry * uInitNumEntries);
  count=0;
}

...
struct Region {
  int lotsOfOtherStuffToo;
  Sll sllParticles;
};
...
  for(int ii = 0; ii < regionsX; ++ii)
      ppRegions[ii] = new Region[regionsY];  // How call the Sll constructor?
```

Comment: Placement new..

Answer (score 0):

The array is a bit of a distraction here.

You have a class `Region` that cannot be default-constructed, because it contains a member of type `Sll` that also cannot be default-constructed. So, you give it a constructor.

Then, with that solved, you are back to the array: how do you create an array of non-default `Region` objects? [By using a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8462922/560648).